# Python code ignoring if - else statement for unknown reason

Tags: python, google-chrome, if-statement

Hi im trying to make a python script which will perform google searches with and without websites that you pick based on keywords. However my script doesn't ignore the search action even when a website variable is empty. Instead it just closes the window. Im really new to Python so I would really appreciate it if someone could nudge me in the right direction on this one.

```
from googlesearch import search
print("Results including the websites you picked:")

if website1 != "":
        for y in keyword_list:
            for i in search(website1+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                print (i)
else:
    print("-None")
if website2 != "":
          for y in keyword_list:
            for i in search(website2+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                print (i)
else:
    print("-None")
if website3 != "":
          for y in keyword_list:
            for i in search(website3+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                print (i)
else:
    print("-None")
if website4 != "":
          for y in keyword_list:
            for i in search(website4+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                print (i)
else:
    print("-None")
if website5 != "":
          for y in keyword_list:
            for i in search(website5+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                print (i)
else:
    print("-None")
    input("press ENTER to continue")

print("Results not including the websites you picked:")
for y in keyword_list:
    for i in search(y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
        print (i)
input("press ENTER to exit")
```

Comment: Where are all these `website1`, etc variables defined?  And `keyword_list`?  How are you running this code?  Is there any error output?

Comment: There is no error output

Comment: and I know that the issue lies within this part of the code

Comment: You have a search near the end of your script which isn't contained in a if block. It might be that?

Comment: @BogamBugami If you could put some addition prints inside each for loop we could see which ones are being triggered.

Comment: All of the loops get triggered when their website variable isn't empty and then when the website variable is empty they get triggered anyway, and because of that it closes the program before the search action for searching without the website criteria activates

Answer (score 0):

I'm also relatively new to python and extremely new to stack overflow so I don't know if I'll be able to be much help.

I tried running your code and it gave me this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlesearch'

I'm not sure if it is the same error that is happening for you, or if my version of python is too outdated, but maybe try checking your capitalisation.

Also, maybe try using elif instead of else as I'm not sure if you can have multiple else statements in a row.

So instead of

```
else:
print("-None")
if website2 != "":
          for y in keyword_list:
            for i in search(website2+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                print (i)
```

try doing

```
elif website2 != "":
  print("-None")
    for y in keyword_list:
       for i in search(website2+y,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1,  start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0):
           print (i)
```

Because of the error message that I mentioned at the beginning, I have no idea if using elif statements instead of the else statements will work or if my answer is any help at all.

I also have a link for a really helpful website for visualising the code execution which has helped me many times, although it doesn't work for a lot of things:
http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Good luck with your code and hopefully something I've said may be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of your code that adds a bit of debugging and removes all the copy+paste.  The added `print`s will show you what `keywords` and `websites` are; I suspect you'll find that one of them is empty and that's why none of your loops are doing anything.

```
from googlesearch import search

websites = [website1, website2, website3, website4, website5]
# Print websites and keywords for debugging.
print(f"Websites: {websites}")
print(f"Keywords: {keywords}")


def print_search_results(website: str) -> None:
    """Loop over all keywords and show results on the given website."""
    for keyword in keyword_list:
        for result in search(
            website + keyword,
            tld='com',
            lang='en',
            num=1,
            start=0,
            stop=1,
            pause=2.0
        ):
            print(result)


print("Results including the websites you picked:")
for website in websites:
    if website:
        print_search_results(website)
    else:
        print("-None")

input("press ENTER to continue")

print("Results not including the websites you picked:")
print_search_results("")

input("press ENTER to exit")
```